# Assign incremental seed to field based on another column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Given: [DEMO Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/328c0/47)

Goal: I'm trying to provide sort values for rows and columns of a pivot talbe.

```
OneTable
Id,GroupId,TopId,TopSort,SideId,SideSort


View1 of OneTable
Id,GroupId,TopId,TopSort
------------------------
1,1,101,null
2,1,101,null
3,1,102,null
4,1,102,null

View2 of OneTable
Id,GroupId,SideId,SideSort
------------------------
1,1,201,null
3,1,201,null
2,1,202,null
4,1,202,null
```

How can I assign a sequence value to TopSort and SideSort per TopId and SideId

For example, take View1 above. Should look like the following:

```
View1 of OneTable
Id,GroupId,TopId,TopSort
------------------------
1,1,101,1
2,1,101,1
3,1,102,2
4,1,102,2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DENSE_RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/foo03871fc6-9592-4016-b0b2-ff543f132b20.aspx) to achieve the desired results, see my [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/328c0/52)

```
SELECT 
  Id,
  GroupId,
  TopId,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TopId ASC) 
FROM Tracker 
ORDER BY TopId;
```